# Approach for Mapstruct Mappers with method overloading and InheritedConfiguration

Tags: mapstruct

We are using MapStruct with Spring Data to convert between JPA entities and DTO classes. All the mappers follow the same pattern with methods beanToDTO() and dtoToBean(). After a learning cure, we have all this working. Now we are trying to use Spring injection to replace the implementation on JPA entity, DTO, and Mapper classes. We have the JPA entities and DTO replacement working. So now we are trying to have Spring inject alternative Mapper implementation.

For our problem, we can subclass the mapper interface and not it will have 2 beanToDTO() methods and 2 dtoToBean methods(), 1 for the base JPA entity and DTO and 1 for the subclassed JPA entity and DTO. This works fine for straightforward examples.

For mappers that require some customization, we utilize the @Mapping annotation and @InheritInverseConfiguration for the base mapper. For the subclassed mapper, we try the same thing but the problem is the InheritInverseConfiguration in the subclass mapper gives the error "Several matching inverse methods exist: beanToDTO(), beanToDTO(). Specify a name explicitly."

Both methods have the same name so we have no way to identify the implementation we want to reference. I realize that the problem is due to our implementation approach but it simplifies our code to:
 - getBean()
 - getMapper().beanToDTO()
and we will be able to replace JPA entity, Mapper , and DTO via Spring injection.

Are there other MapStruct trick that will help us with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `@MapperConfig`.. checkout our unit test. I would advise to put your base / prototype methods in `@MapperConfig` annotated shared configuration interface that you can reference in `@Mapper`

See [this](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/tree/master/processor/src/test/java/org/mapstruct/ap/test/inheritfromconfig) unit test for more info. Or checkout the [user guide](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#shared-configurations).

Comment: I looked at your unit test. To make a match for my system, the method name has to be the same for AutoInheritedConfig.baseDtoToEntity() and CarMapperWithAutoInheritance.toCarEntity(). If you try the change to  CarMapperWithAutoInheritance.baseDtoToEntity(), you will see the issue with multiple matching methods  with the InheritConfiguration methods.

Comment: @MikeRother could you include a small example demonstrating what it is that you wanted to achieve?